# Recursively adding files to JList - only files in last folder are added

Tags: java, file, netbeans, recursion, jlist

struggling again.

I'm recursively searching through a directory and picking out audio files by examining their extensions. Once found, each is to be added to a JList (in the main class - not shown here). However, only the last folder's files are being added to the list. Here is the code:

```
public void List(String path) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        File root = new File(path);
        File[] list = root.listFiles();
        DefaultListModel lm = new DefaultListModel();

        if (list == null) {
            return;
        }

        for (File f : list) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                List(f.getAbsolutePath());

            } else if (f.isFile()) {
                String outPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                try {
                    String ext = outPath.substring(outPath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                    if (ext.equals("wma") || ext.equals("m4a") || ext.equals("mp3")) {
                        lm.addElement(f.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(outPath + " is not a valid file!!!!!");
                }
                HomeScreen.Library.setModel(lm);

            }

        }

    }
```

I've tried replacing the `lm.addElement(f.getAbsolutePath())` with a simple `System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath)` and all files are printed out as expected. I've also tried moving `HomeScreen.Library.setModel(lm);` into different areas but that generally results in nothing being added to the list at all.

What I think must be happening is that each time a new folder is found, the list model is reset, somehow, and the files are added to the now empty model.

Is there a way around this? Am I doing something dopey in my code which is resulting in this apparent reset?

Many thanks in advance,

Guy

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question with a runnable code sample. Please post your code as an [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you create a new `DefaultListModel` in each call of your `List()` method. This explains why you think that

> each time a new folder is found, the list model is reset, somehow, and the files are added to the now empty model

I think you want to add files to the same `DefaultListModel` so create it outside of the `List()` method, and either pass that as a parameter or make it an instance field which `List()` can access.

Comment: Well, mine was faster with 1 minute if you look at the timestamps. Non-accepted answers with equal scores are randomly arranged.

Answer (score 1):

You code create new model every tyme method invoked. You need create model once and update it.

My advice move `DefaultListModel lm = new DefaultListModel();` out of you method and pass reference in it. Also move `HomeScreen.Library.setModel(lm);` out of you method and put it after method call.

```
DefaultListModel lm = new DefaultListModel();
some.List(path, lm);
HomeScreen.Library.setModel(lm);
```

PS: By java name convention method names starts from lover case letter.

Comment: So obvious when you mention it. Thank you very much!